# Canonical "-1 = 1" answer?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

There are quite a few questions which involves "showing" $1=2$ or $0 = 1$ or $-1 = 1$ via incorrect algebraic manipulations of $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Does anyone know if there is a "canonical" question/answer (and if not, would one of our great educators write an answer) that is easily generalisable to at least the usual arithmetic operations?

I'm wondering because of the question " [Why $\sqrt{-1 \times -1} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/i2-why-is-it-1-when-you-can-show-it-is-1#question) ". The suggested "duplicate" target is " [Why $\sqrt{-1 \times {-1}} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/1-is-not-1-so-where-is-the-mistake) ", but I think that for someone who is having difficulties seeing why his/her algebraic manipulations are wrong, the connection between the two questions may not be immediately apparent. (In other words, the answer to the second question may not help.)

And ideally a question of this type should be added to our list here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions

Comment: I think that canonical answer should be $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I $\TeX$-ified [my answer to -1 is not 1, so where is the mistake?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/1-is-not-1-so-where-is-the-mistake/439#439) and added explicit mention of the newer question that you're asking about and the multiplication-of-radicals property.  Offhand, I think that trying to get much more general than what I've written there is, as you suggest, likely to be too general for the people asking such questions.

Comment: perfect, under the basis of http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/